KNN K = 1 Training on itself vs K > 1
When training a $KNN$ algorithm, why is that with $K = 1$, the model trains using the "1 nearest observation to each training point" and treats this as itself resulting in a training error of $0$. Where as for $K = 2$ it would use two neighbours excluding itself.
It seems like the case for training on the 1 nearest (actual) neighbour is missing? Why is this and how would we describe it.
For context to validate this concern i have attached screen shots from the classic ISL textbook. For example one image shows $K = 3$ training on the 3 actual neighbours, the other is a section mentioning the $0$ training error for $K = 1$. Thanks!



In both the $K=1$ and $K>1$ cases, if you ask KNN to classify a training point, it does include that training point as one of the neighbors.
In the left image, the black X is not one of the training points, but a new test point.
In the right image, each of the little dots is not one of the training points either. Only the blue and orange circles are training points.

Hi thank you so much for your reply! As per my post the left image was used as an example where it works as expected. As you rightly say the three neighbours are three neighbours not including itself. So i an understand this image but thank you for clarifying. My confusion was that the text seems to suggest that the K = 1 case, in training it seems to point to itself - hence the reference of "0 training error" as mentioned again in the second image. Snippet at the bottom. If you have more time to clarify with respect to this snippet i would appreciate it, thank you!

Reading your answer again, i think what you are saying is if KNN is run on the training data only. Perhaps to try and suggest the best K. For any K it will always include the training observation as a neighbour when classifying that observation. Because it simply searches for the K nearest neighbour within the training data, and so it finds the same training point there and uses it. And this will be the case for K = 1,2,3,...etc. But you are saying for testing. When we use an unseen point, when it then looks at the trainng data. It simply takes whatever K neighbours it finds to that point.

...continued. I suppose if by chance it happened to find the exact same value in the training data it would count that as one of the neighbours as well. Have i understood, thanks again for your time!

Yes, it sounds like you've got it! If you evaluate KNN on the training data, K=1 will always have 0 training error, but of course it won't fit new/future/test/holdout/validation data perfectly. That is what the snippet of text at the bottom of your post is trying to say. In all of these algorithms, we ought to worry that it might overfit on the training data, then show worse performance on new data; or put another way, training error is a too-optimistic estimate of how well the model will fit new data.

You are thinking of leave-one-out cross-validation (LOOCV), where you try to estimate a point while excluding it from the training data.  In the case of 1-NN, obviously, that means picking the nearest point to the target instead of just picking the target itself.
LOOCV is a good way of evaluating the choice of $k$ in the context of k-NN, and in fact the knn.cv function in the class package in R implements it, as does the caret package: see the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118220/how-can-i-use-loocv-in-r-with-knn for a nice example of this usage all packaged up.
However, once you have fixed $k$, the k-NN algorithm is run using all the data points.  After all, when predicting new values, we want the best possible prediction, which is more likely to be found using all the data than just some of it.  If you predict a value based on an observation already in the dataset, the presumption is that it's not actually the same observation but a different one that's just "co-located" and, consequently, one that might have a different label.  In such a situation, the corresponding observation in the training data (presumably) contains information about the label of the new observation, but it's not 100% accurate information; hence $k > 1$ may be better than $k=1$ at predicting the new label.

Hi I'm so glad you mention this as this is actually something that is confusing me. My Understanding is that the KNN algorithm. 1) Takes a test observation 2) looks in the training set for the K nearest neighbours to that point 3) Classifies the test point based on majority vote of the neighbours....Is this correct? I think from here i am confused about the role of cross validation, as to me that is a separate thing, used for selecting our optimal model. In this case the best K. Would you mind clarrifying the interaction and in which scenario we get the 0 training error with k = 1. Thankyou!

I think my final two comments on the other answer by Civilstat confirm my understanding so far. If you are able to complete the picture with the LOOCV implication that would be fantastic.

I think I may have filled in the blanks for you with an added paragraph...

Thanks again for this. I will let you know as soon as i have absorbed.
